# BASH for loop with find, set variables from command output, then insert into mysql db

Tags: mysql, bash, for-loop

I have 256 directories, each with approximately 55,000 dicom files (these are NOT text files). Each file has meta data that I need to extract, set specified variables, then insert into mysql (actually MariaDB).

I need to keep the original files as is, so first I copy the files from one of the 256 directories from attached storage to a local directory, do another processing item, then go through the list and process each file. The copy and first process took about 20 minutes.

Afterwards I delete all the files locally, then go to the next directory.

Below is the part I think could be optimized, but I'm not sure how... if it was a one-liner process sure, but I think too much has to happen.

I set a variable (all-tags) by taking the output of the dcm2txt command against a file ($i), then set the variables that I need "re-echoing" for each. Is this the most efficient way? The test directory I just processed took a bit over 3 hours for about 55,000 files including 20 minutes to copy and first process, so this part took 2 hours 40 minutes. Only 255 directories to go....

```
logger -t "admin" "loc 2: Truncating files in $PROCESS_DIR"
find $PROCESS_DIR -type f -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/bin/truncate -s -512 {}

cd $PROCESS_DIR
for i in `find . -type f -printf '%f\n'`
do
all_tags=$(/home/admin/securecloud/dcm4che-2.0.29/bin/dcm2txt -w 150 $i)

VARsrc_aet=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0002,0016/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARsop_cuid=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0016/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARsop_iuid=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0018/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARstudy_date=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0020/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARacquis_date=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0022/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARcontent_date=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0023/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARstudy_time=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0030/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARacqis_time=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0032/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARcontent_time=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0033/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARaccession_no=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0050/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARmodality=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0060/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARinstitution=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,0080/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARseries_desc=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,103E/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARops_name=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,1070/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARmanu_model=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0008,1090/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARpat_name=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0010,0010/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARpat_id=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0010,0020/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARpat_birthdate=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0010,0030/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARpat_comments=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0010,4000/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARstudy_iuid=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0020,000D/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARseries_iuid=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0020,000E/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARstudy_id=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0020,0010/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARseries_no=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0020,0011/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
VARinst_no=$(echo "$all_tags" | awk '/0020,0013/' | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)

DB_NAME=ingestion_dir
TABLE=dicom_files

mysql -uname -ppassword $DB_NAME <<EOF
INSERT INTO $TABLE (src_aet,sop_cuid,sop_iuid,study_date,acquis_date,content_date,study_time,acqis_time,\
content_time,accession_no,modality,institution,series_desc,ops_name,manu_model,pat_name,\
pat_id,pat_birthdate,pat_comments,study_iuid,series_iuid,study_id,series_no,inst_no,filename) \
VALUES \
( "$VARsrc_aet", "$VARsop_cuid","$VARsop_iuid", "$VARstudy_date", "$VARacquis_date", "$VARcontent_date", "$VARstudy_time", "$VARacqis_time", \
"$VARcontent_time", "$VARaccession_no", "$VARmodality", "$VARinstitution", "$VARseries_desc", "$VARops_name", "$VARmanu_model", "$VARpat_name", \
"$VARpat_id", "$VARpat_birthdate", "$VARpat_comments", "$VARstudy_iuid", "$VARseries_iuid", "$VARstudy_id", "$VARseries_no", "$VARinst_no", "$i" );

EOF
done
```

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), then edit your question (if you still have one) to follow its advice.

Comment: @chepner - I've read it, and in this case, oranges are not apples... dicom files are not text files. dcm2txt is from a java-based toolkit. A "read" or a "read while" will not work.

Comment: Even though I specified in the original question ("Each file has meta data that I need to extract"), I've edited the question to clearly state that they are dicom files, NOT text files.